# Se e come l'uso di "in" o "nella" influisce sulla comprensione di "entrare in/nella galleria"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> 1. entrare ***in*** galleria può creare problemi
> 2. entrare ***nella*** galleria può creare problemi

Senza informazioni ulteriori, sono il solo a pensare che la galleria riferita in (1) sia una galleria stradale, mentre quella riferita in (2) sia un altro tipo di galleria, per esempio la galleria di un cinema o quella di una miniera?

Se non sono il solo, come mai *in* e *nella* producono questa differente senzazione? Si tratta forse di una questione idiomatica?

Comment: A me non dà questo tipo di sensazione. Di norma userei `in` parlando genericamente e `nella` riferendomi ad una specifica galleria prima menzionata (o comunque sottointesa in qualche modo nel discorso).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Nella* è grammaticalmente definita come una **preposizione articolata**, ossia una preposizione unita ad un articolo determinativo.

In particolare *nella* equivale a *in + la*: la differenza fra le due frasi proposte è che *entrare in galleria* si riferisce al generico atto di entrare in una galleria, mentre *entrare nella galleria* si riferisce ad una galleria particolare (da cui l'utilizzo dell'articolo determinativo *la*).

Bisogna tuttavia notare una sottigliezza. Consideriamo questi due esempi:

> a. Guardare uno spettacolo in galleria costa meno che guardarlo in platea
>
> b. «Vieni a teatro domani sera?»
> «Sì, ma sarò in galleria perchè costa meno»

Nel primo caso ci stiamo riferendo ad una situazione generica: la galleria costa meno della platea, indipendentemente dal teatro.
Nel secondo caso, sebbene la galleria di cui si parla sia specificata (ossia quella del teatro dove i due interlocutori andranno domani sera), si vuole comunque implicare che in generale i biglietti in galleria sono più economici, quindi si usa *in* e non *nella*.

Infine, è anche possibile utilizzare *in* + articolo indeterminativo, per indicare una situazione generica, come nella frase:

> Entrare in una galleria con i fari spenti è pericoloso

Answer (score 5):

*Vado in galleria perché costa meno* could say someone talking about buying the ticket for a cinema. But it would be *nella galleria del cinema Ariston si possono fare brutti incontri*.

You can find the sign *code in galleria*, to mean a generic one or even the next one, if it's clear from the context. But *code nella galleria del Frejus*, if you specify which one.